# ImageSource from String not working?

Tags: c#, wpf, image, imagesource

I have a bunch of *.tif images in a folder in my project..which i've also added to my visual studio project in a folder located "Templates\Team Logos"

now if i set an image source to say:

```
<Image Name="UL_Team1_Image" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Margin="5" Source="Team Logos\ARI.tif"></Image>
```

That works.  But now if i try:

```
UL_ImageArr[a].Source = (ImageSource)new ImageSourceConverter().ConvertFromString("Team Logos\\ARI.tif");
```

that doesn't work. What gives? I get a NullReferenceException... but it doesn't make sense to me?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use this in your code-behind, I think, it is more faster than using `ImageSourceConverter`.

```
BitmapImage bimage = new BitmapImage();
bimage.BeginInit();
bimage.UriSource = new Uri("Team Logos\\ARI.tif", UriKind.Relative);
bimage.EndInit();
UL_ImageArr[a].Source = bimage;
```

If you want to use `ImageSourceConverter` you must refer to image file by pack-uri:

```
var converter = new ImageSourceConverter();
UL_ImageArr[a].Source = 
    (ImageSource)converter.ConvertFromString("pack://application:,,,/Team Logos/ARI.tif");
```

Comment: thanks it worked!  just weird as i've used the convertfromstring feature for a different project and it worked just fine.. not sure why it didn't work for this project.  anyway tyvm!!

Comment: Why so complicated? BitmapImage has a constructor that takes a Uri argument. That saves you the BeginInit and EndInit calls. Just write `UL_ImageArr[a].Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(...));`.

Comment: @Clemens, This is general type of initialization where you can tune the `BitmpSource` between `BeginInit` anf `EndInit` which is impossible in bitmap constuctor initialization.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan Yes, but that isn't necessary here. Keep it simple.

Answer (score 5):

In code behind you will usually write the full [pack URI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069.aspx) to reference image resources.

So you either write

```
UL_ImageArr[a].Source = (ImageSource)new ImageSourceConverter().ConvertFromString(
                        "pack://application:,,,/Team Logos/ARI.tif");
```

or

```
UL_ImageArr[a].Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(
                        "pack://application:,,,/Team Logos/ARI.tif"));
```

or

```
UL_ImageArr[a].Source = BitmapFrame.Create(new Uri(
                        "pack://application:,,,/Team Logos/ARI.tif"));
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are on **WinRt**, use this

```
string url = "ms-appx:///Assets/placeHolder.png";
return new BitmapImage(new Uri(url));
```